# Grails Mapping error when adding a new domain object

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have created a new domain object in an existing Grails 1.3.7 project.

```
package com.xfitlog

class Implement {
    String name
    String description
    String abbreviation

    static belongsTo = [exercise : Exercise]

    static constraints = {
        name( nullable: false, unique: true )
        description( nullable: false, maxSize: 2000 )
        abbreviation( nullable: true )
    }

    String toString() {
        "${name}"   
    }
}
```

This class links to the 'Implement' class.

```
class Exercise{

    String          name
    String          description
    boolean         isApproved
    Implement       implement

    static constraints = {
        name            ( nullable: false )
        description     ( nullable: false, maxSize: 5000 )
        isApproved      ( nullable: true )
        implement       ( nullable: true )
    }

    String toString() {
        "${name}"
    }   
}
```

When I run grails run-app through the windows command prompt I get the following errors:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 's
>   essionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.h ibernate.MappingException: An
>   association from the table exercise refers to an unmapped class:
>   com.xfitlog.Implement
>           ... 28 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException : An
>   association from the table exercise refers to an unmapped class:
>   com.xfitlog.Implement
>           ... 28 more Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table exercise refers to an unmapped class:
>   com.xfitlog.Implement
>           ... 28 more Application context shutting down...

I have tried creating a new project and adding these same domain classes and everything works fine. I don't know what has changed in my original project but something is messed up.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried `grails clean`?

Comment: Make sure the domain classes are in `grails-app/domain` and that the class packages match the directories.

Comment: I have run grails clean several times. The domain classes are in the same package and directory as all of the older classes that are functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not mixing hibernate hbm.xml classes with domain objects. I got a similar error and this turned out to be the issue.

my current app mixes old style groovy pojo ( basically a java pojo written in groovy) using hiberate mapping files in a library and domain classes in the main project.

Also make sure that all of your domain classes have the correct import and package statements.

Comment: Where can I find the hibernate hbm.xml? All of my domain objects are in the <project>\grails-app\domain\com\xfitlog directory.

Comment: From what I have been reading the size of my project may be the cause of this problem. Before I added the 'Implement' domain class I already had 25 other named domain classes. Is anyone else familiar with larger grails projects having this problem?

Comment: I have at least 200 domain classes, and just came across this problem by adding another one ...